# How can I append new "p" element with formatted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function designed to dynamically append text to my document (and slides it down with JQuery). I create a new "p" element, and then I want to add text to it, but I need this text to have several formats. For example, I need the first part to be italicized, second part to be underlined, and third part to be white. As of now, I managed to get three different "div" elements with their own text nodes, each with their own style, but this makes it on three separate lines. I need it all on one line. Is there any way I can insert HTML tags into a text node, or somehow split the internal string up so I can style each part separately?

This code demonstrates the closest I got, but this puts each styled text node on different lines, and I need it all on one line in that p element:

```
function append_announcement(time_string, user_by, text){
    newp = document.createElement("p");

    head = document.createElement("span");
    headt = document.createTextNode("You wrote: ");
    head.appendChild(headt);

    body = document.createElement("div");
    bodyt = document.createTextNode(text);
    body.appendChild(bodyt);
    body.setAttribute("style", "color: white");

    foot = document.createElement("div");
    foott = document.createTextNode("Done.");
    foot.appendChild(foott);

    newp.appendChild(head);
    newp.appendChild(body);
    newp.appendChild(foot);
    newp.setAttribute("align", "center");
    newp.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("announcement_posts").insertBefore(newp,
        document.getElementById("announcement_posts").firstChild);
    $("p").slideDown("slow");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using straight DOM if you have jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `<div>`s for `<span>`s, they're displayed inline by default.

Alternatively you could apply a class to the `<div>` elements you create and set that class to `display: inline-block;` using CSS.

Comment: @Richard: No probs glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FmF9S/8/)

```
function append_announcement(time_string, user_by, text){
    newp = document.createElement("p");

    var i = document.createElement("i");
    i.textContent = ("You wrote ");

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = text;
    span.style.color = "white";

    var u = document.createElement("u");
    u.textContent = " Done.";

    newp.appendChild(i);
    newp.appendChild(span);
    newp.appendChild(u);
    newp.setAttribute("align", "center");
    newp.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("announcement_posts").insertBefore(newp,
        document.getElementById("announcement_posts").firstChild);
    $("p").slideDown("slow");
}
```

You want to create elements that display inline like `<i>`, `<u>` or `<span>`